# Select Product_ID And Sum(Qty) From Another Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, syntax, sum

I have 2 tables, one is a recipe_tbl, and second is prepared_tbl as follow:

recipe_tbl

| Product_ID | Product_Name | Req_Qty | Units |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| F-0001 | Flour | 120 | gr |
| S-0001 | Sugar | 100 | gr |

prepared_tbl

| Trans_Code | Trans_Date | Product_ID | Qty | Units |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| t-2302-001 | 2023-02-16 | F-0001 | 10 | gr |
| t-2302-002 | 2023-02-16 | F-0001 | 10 | gr |
| t-2302-003 | 2023-02-16 | S-0001 | 10 | gr |

What I want is to generate sum as follow:

| Product_ID | Product_Name | Req_Qty | Units | Prepared | Remaining |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| F-0001 | Flour | 120 | gr | 20 | 100 |
| S-0001 | Sugar | 100 | gr | 10 | 90 |

How to do that in query?

This is my query, but it doesn't work :

```
select a.Product_ID , sum(b.Qty) 
from recipe_tbl a  
  left join prepared_tbl b 
on b.Product_ID = a.Product_ID 
group by a.Product_ID
```

Please help we with the correct query, thank you in advance!

```
select a.Product_ID , sum(b.Qty) 
from recipe_tbl a  
  left join prepared_tbl b 
on b.Product_ID = a.Product_ID 
group by a.Product_ID
```

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? Are you getting an error? What is the error?

Comment: [Bad Habits to Kick : Using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3) `a` is for `recipe` and `b` is for `prepared` make little sense, when neither have an `a` or `b` in them respectively.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your advice for table alias. sorry if my statement is confusing, Actually  I have Product_ID that not in Prepared_tbl at all, so when I calculate the remaining qty, it shows null. and the below answer from @Goibsan has shown how to use COALESCE, and it solved my problem. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following SQL query to generate the results you're looking for:

```
SELECT 
    r.Product_ID,
    r.Product_Name,
    r.Req_Qty,
    r.Units,
    SUM(p.Qty) AS Prepared,
    r.Req_Qty - SUM(p.Qty) AS Remaining
FROM recipe_tbl r
LEFT JOIN prepared_tbl p ON r.Product_ID = p.Product_ID
GROUP BY r.Product_ID, r.Product_Name, r.Req_Qty, r.Units;
```

To be in the safe side, when there are no matching rows in the 'prepared_tbl' use **COALESCE** to return 0. Check below query with **COALESCE** function:

```
SELECT 
    r.Product_ID,
    r.Product_Name,
    r.Req_Qty,
    r.Units,
    COALESCE(SUM(p.Qty), 0) AS Prepared,
    r.Req_Qty - COALESCE(SUM(p.Qty), 0) AS Remaining
FROM recipe_tbl r
LEFT JOIN prepared_tbl p ON r.Product_ID = p.Product_ID
GROUP BY r.Product_ID, r.Product_Name, r.Req_Qty, r.Units;
```